# Neo4j: Why do multiple match expressions work but one single match does not?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to return the nodes `h` that have ancestors `camera=red` (red node in the diagram) and `vph=1` (pink node in the diagram).
There are quite a few nodes on the way from those ancestors to `h` and there is more than 1 path for each ancestor which sometimes overlap.
Indeed there each path from each ancestor must pass through a `Run` node before reaching a `File` (green node in the diagram).

[image]
I can run a query:

```
match p1=(:camera {value: 'red'})-[*]->(h:File)
match p2=(:vph {value: 1})-[*]->(h:File)
return h
```

and it returns the nodes. But I don't think that is what I want.

However, when I run:

```
match p1=(:camera {value: 'red'})-[*]->(h),
p2=(:vph {value: 1})-[*]->(h)
where h:File
return h
```

it returns no rows/nodes. This

Why does chaining the expressions in this way not work?
I cannot work out how to export a subgraph so the image is the only thing I can do right now.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I couldn't add the data themselves but I've added a plot

Comment: I tried to reproduce on my machine (running neo4j 4.1.1) the red and green paths in your image, and both of your queries produced the same expected result.

Comment: I've added a screenshot showing that on Neo4j 4.1.0, they return different results

Comment: I created sample data using this query: `CREATE (red:camera {value: 'red'})-[:is_required_by]->(lowRes:File {value: 'LowRes'})-[:is_required_by]->(:File {value: '#c0e0f8'})-[:is_required_by]->(:File {value: '#1c33a0'})-[:is_required_by]->(:File {value: '3130'})-[:is_required_by]->(:File {value: '#9ef04c'})-[:is_required_by]->(h:File {value: '1002813'}),(one:vph {value: 1})-[:indexes]->(h)`. Both of your queries returned the same result. Can you provide sample data that shows the issue?